# How to specify ip and domain with a http request?

Tags: apache, node.js, http, request

I have a apache server and configure some vhosts.

Apache server with ip 172.20.20.20.

A domain url is 'http://www.atest.com/' and another domain url is 'http://www.btest.com/'

In test enviroment, I use firefox with 'Switchhost' plug-in to access Domain A and Domain B.

It works well.

The problem is how can I make a http request by node.js?

my code is here:

```
var options = {
    host: 'http://www.atest.com/',
    port: 80,
    path: '/msg/putMsg',
    method: 'POST'
  };

  var req = http.request(options, function(res){
    var data = '';
    res.setEncoding('utf8');

    res.on('data', function(chunk){
      data += chunk;
    });

    res.on('end', function(){

    });
  });

  req.on('error', function(err){
    console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
  });

  req.write(msg);
  req.end();
}
```

this code snippet works to post some message to Domain A, but dns doesn't work.

Comment: specifying http is kind of redundant if your specified port 80. but i'm not sure if that would make a differnece

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
172.20.20.20 www.atest.com atest.com www.btest.com btest.com
```

to your hosts file (/etc/hosts on Linux /private/etc/hosts on OSX)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system  has locations of the hosts file for other platforms.